# JMeter - Running a JMeter slave from a master results in an RMI Connection Exception

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

I have followed the necessary instructions of setting up a distributed JMeter Testing environment **with JMeter 4.0**.

I have one master and one slave. Both are on the same subnet and I have (whether I should have or not) opened both inward and outward firewall ports for 1099 (for RMI) and 23 on both the master and slave. I could not shut down all the firewall as there is some 'group'policy at my workplace.

I have the necessary rmi_keystore.jks file created with the name as 'rmi' created and their paths referenced correctly in the properties file. I have put them both in the jmeter\bin directories for both slave and master. Hence, it starts the slave object properly.

When I start the master I wait for a bit and eventually get the following:

> ```
> Remote engines have been started
> Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
> c:\XXX\>jmeter -n -t YYY.jmx -r -l ZZZ.jtl -e -o Result
> Creating summariser <summary>
> Created the tree successfully using YYY.jmx
> Configuring remote engine: AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
> Starting remote engines
> Starting the test @ Fri May 18 17:29:19 BST 2018 (xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
> Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to 
> host: AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA; nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
> Remote engines have been started
> Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
> ```

I am not quite sure what else to do as I have followed the necessary instructions hence would really appreciate some help? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Kiril for formatting it correctly for me!

Comment: try disabling firewall and see if it works

Comment: Thanks Rohit. There is some Group Policy which makes it difficult to disable the firewall but will ask either way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the remote engines need to be started manually.
Be sure you started them before starting the master.

Furthermore, if the master has two (or more)  interfaces, you need to specify the one where RMI server sits and listens.